# How can docker-runc be used inside a container?

Tags: docker

What is necessary to enable `docker-runc` to work inside a container?

The following command will list the plugins, but with PID = 0 and status = stopped. Are additional volumes needed?

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /run/docker/plugins/runtime-root/plugins.moby:/run/docker/plugins/runtime-root/plugins.moby docker docker-runc --root /run/docker/plugins/runtime-root/plugins.moby list
```

Result:

```
ID                                                                 PID         STATUS      BUNDLE                                                                                                                                       CREATED                          OWNER
abf6245ea65ee121ff48c30f99c283dac49d225221579ee4a140b7d8a843f200   0           stopped     /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/plugins.moby/abf6245ea65ee121ff48c30f99c283dac49d225221579ee4a140b7d8a843f200   2018-11-01T16:26:26.605625462Z   root
```

Comment: If you’re trying to control the host’s Docker daemon, it seems like it’d be appropriate and simpler to run a privileged (root) process on the host.

Comment: The use case is a Docker container used as a build agent for a CI server. Mapping `/var/run/docker.sock` enables the build agent to spin up and down containers, etc. In this case, I am trying to execute a command on a managed plugin using `docker-runc exec`, but that doesn't work.

I could of course install the build agent on the host, but it is much cleaner and simpler to use a container.